# Sorting of pfquery with multiple conditions for iOS7

Tags: ios, parse-platform

i am trying to sort a pfquery with multiple conditions, the code below sorts only one column. please help.

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    [query whereKey:@"mStatus" equalTo:@"running"];
    [query orderByAscending:@"mName"];
    [query orderByAscending:@"mOrder"];
    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    [query whereKey:@"mStatus" equalTo:@"running"];
    [query orderByAscending:@"mName"];
    [query addAscendingOrder:@"mOrder"];
    return query;
}
```

Comment: will the above code have order of sorting ? like mName will be on first priority and order will be on second priority?

Comment: yes i already found that. thanks a lot. your answer saved me :)